# (Prolog) Finding neighbors in a list

Tags: list, prolog

We have to write a Prolog predicate `neighbors(X,Y,L)` which is true if `L` is a list and `X` and `Y` are neighbor elements in the list. So far I wrote:

```
neighbors(X,X,[X]).
neighbors(X,Y,[X,Y|R]):- neighbors(X,Y,R).
neighbors(X,Y,[Y,X|R]):- neighbors(X,Y,R).`
```

but the output would always give (obviously) empty brackets ( "`[]`" ) no matter the input. So can you guys give me some advice on how to improve this predicate?
We recently started with the Prolog so I still need some practise with it.

Comment: What's the idea behind `neighbors(X,X,[X]).`? It appears more than a little odd to me. Please explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use append :

```
neighbors(X,X,[X]).

neighbors(X,Y,L) :-
      append(_, [X,Y|_], L)
    ; append(_, [Y,X|_], L).
```

Comment: I have a small suggestion on readability: Everyone reading this is likely to misread `;` as `,`, because the symbols look so similar and `,` typically appears at the end of a line. My suggestion therefore is to always put `;` **in front** of the (next) line in such cases.

Comment: Nice! That's a good solution, +1. The layout I would recommend for this is to use parentheses, and indentation also for the first line: `;` is the primary functor, and both goals are arguments.

Comment: I get what you mean, why not  **;(append( _ , [X,Y| _ ], L),append( _ , [Y,X| _ ], L)).**

Comment: Also OK, though it is more common in Prolog to use infix notation when possible, like in `X #= 3+5` instead of `#=(X, +(3,5))`, which would also be perfectly valid. One good alternative is sometimes `( G1 ; G2 )`, i.e., both goals on a single line. The thing that must be prevented at all costs is `;` at the *end* of a line, because it looks too similar to `,`.

Comment: That `neighbors(X,X,[X]).` has to be wrong - cannot have 2 neighbors, i.e. 2 elements, in `[X]`.

Answer (score 1):

So I kinda kept trying and found the answer by myself.

I had to consider 2 cases:

1. X and Y is neighbor with X,Y so `neighbors(X,Y,[X,Y|_]).`
2. X and Y is neighbor with Y.X so `neighbors(X,Y,[Y,X|_]).`

And also we have to check through the whole list skipping every element which is irrelevant to us (all elements that does not match X or Y). That can be done using a recursion `neighbors(X,Y,[F,S|R]) :- neighbors(X,Y,[S|R]).`

so the whole predicate should be

```
neighbors(X,Y,[X,Y|_]). 
neighbors(X,Y,[Y,X|_]).
neighbors(X,Y,[F,S|R]) :- neighbors(X,Y,[S|R]).
```

so far, this gives the correct outputs for every input but if there is still something wrong then please advise me on it. Thanks.

Comment: There is a small typo in your answer below: you forgot to close the square bracket...

Answer (score -2):

```
neighbors(X,Y,Z) :- append(_,[X|[Y|_]],Z).
```

Comment: That just results in a syntax error. What is the first argument in `append/3` meant to be?

Comment: Now it ignores Y potentially being immediately *before* X.